# How to delete duplicates and leave one row in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, sql-delete

I have table which looks like this. I want to delete duplicates and leave one row for each user. How do I go about this?

*Table**

```
id     user 
Thango   1

Thango  1 

Samg     2

Samg     2
```

**Results**

id     user

```
Thango   1

Samg     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this dataset, it is probably simpler to just empty and refill the table:

```
-- deduplicate into a temporary table
create table mytmp as select distinct id, user from mytable;

-- empty the original table (backup your data first!)
truncate table mytable;

-- refill the table from the temporary table
insert into mytable(id, user) select id, user from mytmp;

-- drop the temporary table
drop table mytemp;
```

Once this is done, you might consider creating a `unique` constraint on the table to avoid further duplicates:

```
alter table mytable
    add constraint myconstraint
    unique (id, user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use Common Table Expressions (CTE). For a better explanation I advise you to take a look into this [url](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/delete-duplicate-record-from-sql-data-table-using-cte)

A possible solution:

```
WITH CTE([user], 
duplicatecount)
AS (SELECT [user],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [user]
           ORDER BY [id]) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM dbo.[YourDataBase])
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
```